# Go to react to Ctrl + D

Tags: go, panic

I often use `Ctrl + d` to shut down Go programs that is being run by `go run` or in binary. How do I make the code to react to this unexpected input `ctrl + d` ? For example, I am running a script that creates `EC2` containers but I cancel the program during run time. Then I want this code to react to this `ctrl + d` and terminate the `EC2` before it is shut down.

Please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: `Ctrl-D` sends EOF which doesn't make sense when you're not getting input. Use `Ctrl-C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ctrl-C, the process receives a KILL signal.

You can catch it with os/signal, read the example for the detail:

http://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#pkg-examples